# How to produce a wavy effect?

Tags: software, photo-editing, android-app, software-filters

What photo app or editor can be used to produce this wavy effect?

[image]

Comment: Why the Android tag ? Has it been made with a cellphone ?

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Comment: Looks like it could have been done on camera by some sort of temporal distortion, anyone here from physicsSE?

Comment: @CrazyDino, pretty sure Doctor Who was entering just off-stage to the left, causing space-time to wobble when this picture was taken. Fortunately, jelly-legs symptoms usually resolve themselves after a few hours.

Comment: @Corey No timey-wimey sci-fi explanation needed: the soles of the subject's shoes were covering up co-orbiting black holes just prior to their collision, causing gravitational waves to emanate from under his feet, which caused distortions in the paths of nearby photons. Simple. =)

Comment: @scottbb - Then how do you explain the epic face-palm? It is clear that the good Doctor *must* have tripped on exit of his craft...yet again...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's probably a filter or app out there - but here's the Photoshop answer: [Use Liquify](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/liquify-filter.html).

The image looks like the artist simply ran a liquify brush through the bottom half of the photo semi-randomly. (Up/Down movements on the left and right, side to side movement on the legs).

Answer (score 0):

Distortion effects in Photoshop or Gimp, **but** applied to separate color channels with slight difference in ripple parameters. Thus you get those orange/bluish edges.

Comment: I think the orange/blue may just as well be chromatic aberration that's been stretched (thus appearing more prominent than it originally was)

Comment: From experience this is a graphic editor effect. I used to reproduce it many times in Photoshop by using Difference selector applied to a layer above. Especially prominent when one layer is mostly blue, and the other is the difference (which becomes orange).